# Yii2 return single value of attribute on condition

Tags: database, model, yii2, return

I have these tables in the database:

- user       : userid (primary Key), professionid, etc,
- profession : professionid (primary Key), classid, etc,
- class      : classid (primary key), etc,

In model of User, I create function,

```
public function getClassid()
{
   return 1;
}
```

How can I replace 1 to value of classid in table of profession, where userid is current logged user?

Comment: Do you have definied relations in your `User` model?

Comment: yes, in my User model

public function getProfession()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Profession::className(), ['professionid' => 'professionid']);
    }

Comment: So you can just `return $this->getProffesion() ? $this->getProffesion()->classid : null`.

Comment: @Yupik $this->getProffesion() will return activeQuery so  this `$this->getProffesion()->classid` will throw error. `$this->getProffesion()->one()->classid` can work.

Comment: @Golub my bad, forgot about this. Just change to `return $this->profession ? $this->profession->classid : null`.

Comment: Thanks @Yupik and Golub, but I'm still getting error:
Using $this when not in object context,

I use that function to make filter in ModelSearch (JobSearch):
$query->andFilterWhere([
...
'classid' => $this->classid=User::getClassid(),
...
]);

when getClassid() {return 1;} the gridview only displays the job according to classid=1 (matching between User and Job)

Comment: You can't use **non-static** function (`User::getClassid()`) as a **static** one! Normally it will rise a notice! If you want to get `classid` for current user, and have proper configuration of `user` component, you can get it by `Yii::$app->user->identity->classid`.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
return model->profession->classid
```

Comment: That's not best idea. In case where there's not related model you have unhandled notice here: `Trying to get property of non-object`.

Comment: @Yupik is right, you can use getValue function `ArrayHelper::getValue($model, 'profession.classid')`

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
public function getClassid()
{
   $profession = Profession::findOne(['professionid' = > $this->profession_id])
   return $profession->classid;
}
```

This returns the value of the attribute `classid` which is stored in the table `Profession` where the `professionid` is the same and the `professionid` of the current `User` model.

Hope this helps